# Why is Angular not able to find main.js and pollyfills.js?

Tags: angular, nginx, deployment, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an `Angular Universal` code which works on my local machine but not on the server. So, I think some kind of settings and configurations on the server are not correct. But I can't find what exactly is wrong.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBOLD.jpg) is the structure of my project on the server.

The errors I get are the followings:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCuav.jpg).

And here is how the website looks like:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHgC2.jpg).

As you see, the code is somehow deployed and shown but not properly.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjwqZ.jpg) you can find the configuration of `nginx`.

And here are the steps I follow to deploy the code on the server:

```
1)  ng build --configuration production –aot
2)  npm run build:ssr
3)  Upload the files to the correct folders
4)  pm2 kill
5)  sudo pm2 start /var/www/myApp.com/html/server/ecosystem.config.js
6)  pm2 startup systemd
7)  systemctl restart nginx
```

And here is my `index` file:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Something</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
  <meta name="description" content="something">
  <meta name="keywords" content="something">

 <meta name="google-site-verification" content="6xXxEb-Y" />
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="O_PI" />
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="something.js"></script>

</html>
```

In the meantime, if I do NOT comment out the line in the nginx configuration (the green line in the picture), I will not have anything in my `app-root` on page source. When I comment it out, the app-root gets filled but not everything on the website is showing correctly.

I hope somebody can help me, what I have done wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What backend stack are you using to host the angular app?

Comment: @Pieterjan You mean the backend language? The backend is developed in java and it is deployed on a Linux Server using Nginx. Does it answer your question?